# SQL Server database migration permissions

Tags: sql-server

We are replacing an old 32 bit server (Windows Server 2008, SQL Server 2008 Express) with a new 64 bit server (Windows Server 2016, SQL Server 2016 Express). I have to migrate a database to the new server as part of the process.

SQL Server was originally configured for mixed mode authentication and as such my application required an `sa` username and appropriate password to access the data in the database.

SQL Server on the new server is configured for Windows Authentication. I have migrated the database but my application now cannot access the data. I suspect, but could be wrong, that there is no `sa` user account but I am not very knowledgeable in this area.

Can anyone advise how I can either alter the access privileges for the migrated database to allow access or create a `sa` user account to match the original environment please.

Comment: can we see some error messages please from the failed connectoin attempt

Comment: You can configure the new server to use mixed mode and create a sql server account on it for your application. Running your applications as the sa user is a terrible practice you should avoid.

Comment: The possible solution also depends on the type (and platform) of your application.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt comments. The error is: `Connection Error!: SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.`

Comment: what process is connecting to the server, and what is the permission level of that user at server level?

Comment: here is some guidance for you to follow, it appears that the error relates to a problem in the connection to the server, not authentication against that server.  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_protocols/2007/07/19/tcp-provider-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it/

Comment: Also you are now on a 64 bit platform, have you setup the 64bit drivers for ODBC? because you will need these, this could potentially be your issue?

Comment: Some more details. 64 bit server. PHP 7. php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll php driver which is enabled in the php.ini file.

Comment: I have an application which accesses the SQL database by creating a PDO object and connecting. The PHP script, which of course works fine on the current server, sets `$serverName = '127.0.0.1,1433'` along with the database name, username and password. Here the 'sa' username and password are set.

Comment: if it was failing to authenticate you would have got a logon failed erro as opposed to a connection error, there is something wrong with your connection path somewhere or a driver issue.

Comment: I can connect and view the database content using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), can I test the connection to `127.0.0.1,1433` or gather some information from the SSMS properties?

Comment: it may be better to continue this in chat as comments getting long.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144545/discussion-between-jimmy8ball-and-tdc).

Answer (score 0):

Open SSMS, right click on sql server instance name >>Select Property>>select security in that change the server authentication from windows authentication mode to Sql server and windows authentication mode then restart sql server and try login with sa user.

Thanks,
Manish

Comment: "...and try to login with sa user" Do you mean try to connect to the database from the application, or is there a way to actually login to the database please?

Comment: as per your error its not related with authentication problem and  "try to login with sa use" i though earlier it was related with authentication issue.